# Dynamic Terraform Backend

Tags: terraform, digital-ocean

I'm wanting to build an infrastructure on Digital Ocean using terraform.
One problem I encountered was the following:

I need to create a CDN on Digital Ocean and use this CDN as the backend for Terraform State, but apparently the terraform backend is having problems using references from this CDN creation, I'll leave a code example here:

Creation of the CDN:

```
# Create a new Spaces Bucket
resource "digitalocean_spaces_bucket" "mybucket" {
  name   = "example"
  region = "sfo2"
  acl    = "public-read"
}

# Add a CDN endpoint to the Spaces Bucket
resource "digitalocean_cdn" "mycdn" {
  origin = digitalocean_spaces_bucket.mybucket.bucket_domain_name
}

# Output the endpoint for the CDN resource
output "fqdn" {
  value = digitalocean_cdn.mycdn.endpoint
}
```

Creation of the backend:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    endpoint                    = digitalocean_cdn.mycdn.endpoint
    bucket                      = "example"
    key                         = "terraform.tfstate"
    region                      = "sfo3"
    access_key                  = "access_key"
    secret_key                  = "secret_key"
    skip_credentials_validation = true
    skip_metadata_api_check     = true
    skip_region_validation      = true
  }
}
```

Error message after running `terraform init`:

```
Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: Variables not allowed
│ 
│   on backend.conf line 1:
│    1: endpoint                    = digitalocean_cdn.mycdn.endpoint
│ 
│ Variables may not be used here.
╵
```

I would like to know how I use the backend with the CDN that is being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s as it says in the error message “variables not allowed”. You cannot use variables in the backend block.